# Should std::vector::swap() with stateful allocators invalidate all iterators?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

Given allocators `a1` and `a2`, where `a1` != `a2`,

and `std::vector`s `v1(a1)` and `v2(a2)`

then `v1.swap(v2)` invalidates all iterators.

Is this expected behavior?

Comment: I don't think that this is specific to Visual Studio.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In general, `swap` never invalidates iterators.  However, another rule comes into play when the allocators are different.  In that case the behavior depends on `allocator_traits<a1>::propagate_on_container_swap::value` and `allocator_traits<a2>::propagate_on_container_swap::value`.  If both are true, the allocators are exchanged along with the data, all iterators remain valid.  If either is false, behavior is undefined, so the particular behavior exhibited by VC++ 2010 is allowed.

From `[container.requirements.general]` (wording from n3290):

> Allocator replacement is performed by copy assignment, move assignment, or swapping of the allocator only if `allocator_traits<allocatortype>::propagate_on_container_copy_assignment::value`,
>   `allocator_traits<allocatortype>::propagate_on_container_move_assignment::value`, or `allocator_traits<allocatortype>::propagate_on_container_swap::value` is true within the implementation of the corresponding container operation. The behavior of a call to a container’s swap function is undefined unless the objects being swapped have allocators that compare equal or `allocator_traits<allocatortype>::propagate_on_container_swap::value` is true.

and

> Every iterator referring to an element in one container before the swap shall refer to the same element in the other container after the swap

and

> Unless otherwise specified ...  no `swap()` function invalidates any references, pointers, or iterators referring to the elements of the containers being swapped.

23.3.6.5 does not specify alternate rules for `vector::swap()`.

Comment: I could not find "allocator_traits" in any of the include files for VS2010. So I do not think VS2010 supports this feature.  However your answer shows me that this is in the undefined realm, which answers my concerns on the issue.

Comment: @jyoung: The definition in the standard is "Type: Alloc::propagate_on_container_swap if such a type exits, otherwise false_type."  So I suppose you can look at the allocator class definition instead.

Comment: "propagate_on_container_swap" is not in there either. Looking at vector.swap, I only see code refering to == for allocators.

Comment: @jyoung: From the wording "if such a type exists, otherwise `false_type`", I think that we're solidly in the case where `propagate_on_container_swap::value` is not `true`, and therefore the behavior of `swap()` is undefined if the allocators aren't equal.